# Can I use "I start school at 8 o'clock every day" meaning "I start classes at 8 o'clock every day"?

Tags: word-choice

Can "start school at 8.00 every day" be used with the same meaning as "start classes at 8.00 every day"? I know that it usually means begin school at a certain age, say five or six. Can school mean the classes I go to?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is acceptable and people will completely get your meaning. "8 o'clock" is a bit formal, and people generally say

> I start school at 8 every day.

You can also use this pattern for other things, for example:

> I start work at 8 every day.